# What is difference between merge query and query with cursor for update and insert of data in terms of performance optimization and scalability?

Tags: sql

What is difference between merge query and query with cursor for update and insert of data in terms of performance optimization and scalability?

Any answer is much appreciated

Sql

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: MSQL 2008 its is